# ошибка as_view() в urls.py Django

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

Пытаюсь добавить возможно редактирования таблицы, но выдает ошибку:

Generic detail view GroupUpdateView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.

HTML code:

```
{% extends 'main/doki.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="groupcont">
            <div class="disian-camp">
                <a href="{% url 'create2' %}"><li><button class="btn btn-info"><i class "fas fa-plus-circle"><i> Добавить новую таблицу</button></li></a>
                    <table class="disian-campe">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>id</th>
                                <th>Номер группы</th>
                                <th>ФИО Куратора</th>
                                <th>Редактирование</th>
                                <th>Удаление</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% for el in groups %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ el.titleid }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ el.titlegroup1 }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ el.titlecurator }}</td>
                                    <td><a href="{% url 'create2' %}">Редактировать</a></td>
                                    <td><a href="">Удалить</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
            </div>


{% endblock %}
```

second HTML code:

```
{% extends 'main/doki.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %} Страница добавления таблиц {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="createtable2">
        <style>
        form {
            margin-left: 32%;
            width: 500px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        </style>
            <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.titleid }} <br>
                {{ form.titlegroup1 }} <br>
                {{ form.titlecurator }} <br>
                <button class "btn btn-success" type="submit">Добавить таблицу</button>
            </form>
    </div>


{% endblock %}
```

urls.py code:

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.registration, name='home'),
    path('group', views.about, name='group'),
    path('students', views.students, name='students'),
    path('create', views.create, name='create'),
    path('create2', views.create2, name='create2'),
    path('group/update', views.GroupUpdateView.as_view(), name='group/update'),
    path('student/update', views.StudentUpdateView.as_view(), name='student/update')
]
```

views.py code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import group
from .models import studentes
from .forms import studentForm
from .forms import groupForm
from django.views.generic import DetailView, UpdateView


def registration(request):
    return render(request, 'main/registration.html')

def about(request):
    groups = group.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/group.html', {'groups':groups})

def students(request):
    studentss = studentes.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/students.html', {'studentss':studentss})


def create(request):
    error = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = studentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('student')
        else:
            error = 'Ошибка формы. Пожалуйста, проверьте правильность веденных данных'

    form = studentForm()

    data = {
        'form': form,
        'error': error
    }

    return render(request, 'main/create.html', data)

def create2(request):
    error = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = groupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('group')
        else:
            error = 'Ошибка формы. Пожалуйста, проверьте правильность веденных данных'
        
    form = groupForm()

    data = {
        'form': form,
        'error': error
    }


    return render(request, 'main/create2.html', data)

class StudentUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = studentes
    template_name = 'main/create.html'

    fields = ('titleid2', 'titlegroup2', 'titlestudent', 'titlephone', 'titleemail')

class GroupUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = group
    template_name = 'main/create2.html'

    fields = ('titleid', 'titlegroup1', 'titlecurator')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что Вы не передаете идентификатор группы в urls.py

Должно быть так:

```
path('group/<int:pk>/update/', views.GroupUpdateView.as_view(), name='group/update'),
```

По умолчанию UpdateView ищет конкретный объект по полю PK.